# Saving parameters from hidden_field to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to save a service_name from a hidden field to a service_name column in a servicebooking model. Service has many servicebookings, can anyone help?

///passing service_name to be saved in servicebooking model with new_servicebooking_path

```
<%= link_to 'Book this service', new_servicebooking_path(service_name: @service.name) %>
```

///hidden fields in service show view:

```
    <%= f.hidden_field :service_name, :value => @service.try(:name)  %>
```

///Defining @service variable in servicebookings controller's new method

```
def new
   @service = Service.find(params[:service_name])
   @servicebooking = @service.servicebookings.new
 end
```

//Services edit form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :service_name, @service.try(:name)  %>
```

//Servicebooking model setting service name to be saved

```
after_validation :set_service_name

  def set_service_name
    self.service_name = service.try(:name)
  end
```

Currently no service_name is saved in the servicebooking model???

Answer (score 1):

is the primary key of the service model is the name instead of the id? if not, i believe the code above should raise an error while executing `@service = Service.find(params[:service_name])`

You can try this

in servicebookings controller

```
def new
  @service = Service.find_by_name(params[:service_name])
  @servicebooking = @service.servicebookings.new(service_name: params[:service_name])
end
```

in servicebookings edit form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :service_name  %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ahmed, I get the following NoMethodError when running your code: undefined method `servicebookings' for nil:NilClass raised by the following line in my servicebookings controller create method:  @servicebooking = current_user.servicebookings.build(params[:servicebooking].permit(:date, :time, :service_name, :service_id, :user_id)) any idea why it doesnt save?

Comment: this means that **current_user** is nil and hence `current_user.servicebookings` raised this error. make sure that there  is a **signed in** user.